# Can't use resolution > 1080p for external display over HDMI on wayland

Tags: linux, wayland, resolution

As in the title, I cannot set higher resolution than 1080p on an external monitor over HDMI. I have a Xiaomi Mi Air 13.3 (2016) and this problem occurs regardless of kernel or anything. I can add the resolution with the help of xrandr and it works, but the result does not satisfy me because I would like to use wayland, but I can't because there manually add the resolution can't be done.

I checked another laptop from HP where the processor is i5-6300U (my i5-5200U), both have the same graphics chip and everything is working fine.

Can someone explain it to me? What could be the problem?

Comment: What OS and version?

Comment: I've tried on probably every more well-known distribution... fedora, enderours os, zorin os, ubuntu etc. On every distro the same issue so.
At this moment im on Zorin Os 16.